# Integral involving BesselJ functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, special-functions

In [this paper, page 252](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3596359), there is an equality (D.69), the numerical results integrals on the left is of interest:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{x\cdot J_0(x\cdot r)}{x^2-k^2}dx=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{i \cdot\pi \cdot  H_0^{(1)}(k\cdot r)}{2}&\text{Im}(k)>0 \\
\\
 \dfrac{i \cdot\pi \cdot  H_0^{(2)}(k\cdot r)}{2} &\text{Im}(k)<0\\
\end{array}
\right. \tag{D.69}$$

Where $J_0$ is the [BesselJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), $H_0$'s are the [Hankel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Hankel_functions)s respectively.

I don't know how to prove the integral equality or whether it holds only for the `non-real` $k$'s .

But I am interested in the numerical (or analytical when possible) result when $k$ is a real positive number.

But how to obtain a numerical solution of such integrals? e.g., I tried to let $k=10$ and $r=6$, but found most of the available integral algorithms in `NIntegrate` didnot lead to easy convergence probably due to the existence of a discontinuity point $x=k$ of the integrand and the improper upper limit.

e.g..

```
NIntegrate[(x BesselJ[0, 6 x])/(x^2 - 100), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"OscillatorySelection", "TermwiseOscillatory" -> True, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

gives

> 0.155652

and warning messages:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {10.0009}. NIntegrate obtained 0.16591870616051807`and 0.2705956661691797` for the integral and error estimates.

Comment: The integration doesn't converge:  `Integrate[(x BesselJ[0, 6 x])/(x^2 - 100), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integrate[(x BesselJ[0, r x])/(x^2 - k^2), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> k > 0 && r > 0]
(* 1/2 π BesselY[0, k r] *)

N[% /. k -> 10 /. r -> 6]
(* -0.0743913 *)
```

Comment: You only took half of the domain in the OP's integral.

Comment: @J.M.  OP's actual code shows the integral from `zero` to `Infinity`, so I presume that is what he meant.  Furthermore, the integrand is antisymmetric, so the integral from `-Infinity` to `Infinity` is zero.

Comment: Indeed, so we'll have to wait for OP to clarify. The only problem now is $k=0$, where the integral is genuinely divergent.

Comment: Thank you. This already answers my question